# Not able to access IMAP/POP3 gmail

Tags: openssl, gmail, imap, telnet

I am trying to access Gmail IMAP/POP3 Via Telnet or OpenSSL Client but its giving connect: Connection timed out.

I have Tried:

OpenSSL

```
 openssl s_client -starttls imap -connect imap.gmail.com:993
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993`. `-starttls imap` is for port 143, not for 993.

Comment: Imap port 143 is without SSL where as 993 is with SSL.
Reference: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/DE5mVMSh1vk

Comment: TLS is used on port 143 as specified by [the IMAP RFC, section 6.2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.2.1). Support for that  [has been mandatory since 2003,](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.1.1) ie. if a server listens on port 143 it must offer TLS on that port.